# Software as both product and service?

Tags: distribution

Can someone give an example of software that is distributed as **both** service and product and how to classify, if i have to eventually, under one category?

Comment: Atlassian does this. But it is not opensource.

Answer (score 1):

> Can someone give an example of software that is distributed as both service and product

An example that comes quickly to mind is [Wordpress](https://wordpress.org/).  It's [distributed under GPLv2+](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WordPress), so you can take a copy and install it on your own website, as very many people do.  Most major distros repackage it, to make doing your own installation very easy (CentOS 7: `yum install epel-release ; yum install wordpress`).  However, you can also buy Wordpress site hosting as a service, from many providers ([example 1](https://uk.godaddy.com/hosting/wordpress-hosting), [example 2](https://www.resellerclub.com/wordpress-hosting), [example 3](https://www.fasthosts.co.uk/web-hosting/wordpress), and I should stress these are taken from the results of a duckduckgo search and their selection implies no endorsement whatsoever).

> how to classify, if i have to eventually, under one category

I'm sorry, I don't understand that question.  If you mean "*how do I decide whether I'm distributing software or offering SaaS*", the question to ask yourself is "*am I giving copies of software to people to run on their own computers, or am I running it on my own computer and letting them use it?*".